# How to add border color to an html character using css?

Tags: html, css, pandas, css-selectors

I am currently tasked to create checks inside of a pandas DataFrame table of different colors when certain data is showing.

I was able to find the following:

```html
<p>I will display <span style="color:green">&#10004;</span></p>
<p>I will display <span style="color:yellow">&#x2714;</span></p>
```

While this works per se ... It would be nice to have them bigger if possible, or at least a border around the check itself (not a box around it).

Clearly this is not the way to go since it's an ASCII character, so curious if anyone had found a similar need. Google only returns checkbox information, not a check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `text-shadow` to add a border around your tick-mark icon. Also, you can further improve readability by increasing the size of the icons.

---

Check the **Code Snippet** below for a practical example of using `text-shadow` and increasing the icon size:

```css
    p:nth-child(1) span {color:green; text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black; font-size: 50px;}

    p:nth-child(2) span {color:yellow; text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;}
```

```html
<p>I will display <span>&#10004;</span></p>
<p>I will display <span>&#x2714;</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a box by border and make the font-size change as done in the snippet.

Another option is you can Search google with keywords **checkbox fafa icon** or **check icon fafa**

```html
<p>I will display <span style="border: 1px solid black;font-size: 50px;color:green">&#10004;</span></p>
<p>I will display <span style="color:yellow">&#x2714;</span></p>
```

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear - a border around the actual check. But that font size helps ensure it's readable! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

An approach with better reusability would be to create the checkmark via a CSS class on a *pseudo element*  `::before` or `::after`:

```css
.checkmark-before::before,
.checkmark-after::after {
  content: "✔";
  color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.checkmark-before.x2::before,
.checkmark-after.x2::after {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.checkmark-before.bordered::before,
.checkmark-after.bordered::after {
  text-stroke: 1px #a00;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #a00; 
  width: 1.2em;
}

.checkmark-before.yellow::before,
.checkmark-after.yellow::after {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button class="checkmark-after" type="button">I will display </button>

<p class="checkmark-before x2"> Done!</p>

<a href="http://example.com" class="checkmark-after bordered"> Google</a>

<p  class="checkmark-before x2 checkmark-after yellow bordered">Combined!</p>
```

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear - a border around the actual check. But that font size helps ensure it's readable! Thank you

Comment: Either use `text-stroke` or `text-shadow` for that. I've adjusted the sample to use `text-stroke`.

Comment: perfect - thank you! too bad I can only choose one response as the answer :(

Comment: You can upvote as many as you like, though. Also you can always re-pick your answer :D